# Changing React button text upon Login/Logout

Tags: reactjs, authentication, authorization

I'm fairly new to React and am working on making an app that involves a sign in/login. I have my login button on my nav bar and I wish to change the text so that when the user logs in the text of the button changes to "Loggout" and vice versa.

```
class SiteBar extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        isOpen: false,


    };
}
toggle() {
    this.setState({
        isOpen: !this.state.isOpen,
    });
}
render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <div>
            <Navbar color="faded"  light expand="md">
                <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen} navbar>
                    <Nav className="ml-auto" navbar>
                        <NavItem>
                            <Button color="light" onClick={() => this.props.clickLogout()}>{this.onClick ? 'Login' : 'Logout'}</Button>
                        </NavItem>
                    </Nav>
                </Collapse>
            </Navbar>
        </div>
```

Keeping in mind I am passing a function to my main app file, any advice is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to use state instead of click function in condition. because react change UI on state change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add a state to the class where you defined this.props.clickLogout

```
this.state = {
    isLoggedIn: false
}
```

Then, you also pass the props from that class and pass the state as a prop.

```
<SiteBar clickLogOut={this.clickLogOut} isLoggedIn={this.state.isLoggedIn}/>
```

The condition for the text of the button would be the prop `isLoggedIn`. When the button fires the onClick function, the function `clickLogout()` should change the `isLoggedIn` to true, thus re-rendering ClassSite and the button with the text Logout

```
<Button color="light" onClick={() => this.props.clickLogout()}>
    {this.props.isLoggedIn? 'Logout' : 'Login'}
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an older post but i just wanted to throw in this as a possible solution.

```
class SiteBar extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props) 
    this.state = {
        isOpen: false
    }
       this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
}
toggle() {
    this.setState(prevState => {
        return {
            isOpen: !prevState.isOpen
        }
    });
}
render() {
    let btnTxt = this.state.isOpen ? 'Login' : 'Logout'
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Navbar color="faded"  light expand="md">
                <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen} navbar>
                    <Nav className="ml-auto" navbar>
                        <NavItem>
                            <Button color="light" onClick={this.toggle}>{btnTxt}</Button>
                        </NavItem>
                    </Nav>
                </Collapse>
            </Navbar>
        </React.Fragment>
```